# Evaluating the nested radical $ \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}} $.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, nested-radicals

How does one prove the following limit?
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty}
  \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots \sqrt{1 + (n - 1) \sqrt{1 + n}}}}}
= 3.
$$

Comment: In this video https://youtu.be/r5BGIi84arY by MindYourDecisions explains the "Ramanujan's radical brain teaser".

Comment: Also check out his blog post https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2016/05/01/ramanujans-nested-radical-sunday-puzzle/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is the special case $\rm\ x,\:n,\:a = 2,\:1,\:0\ $ in Ramanujan's second notebook, chapter XII, entry 4:

$$\rm x + n + a\ =\ \sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 + x\sqrt{a(x+n) + (n+a)^2 + (x+n) \sqrt{\cdots}}} $$

Below is Ramanujan's solution of the given special case - which was submitted to a journal in April 1911. Note that his solution is incomplete (exercise: why?). For further discussion see this 1935 Monthly article, [Herschfeld: On infinite radicals.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2301294)  It also appeared as Problem A6 on the 27th Putnam competition, 1966. Vijayaraghavan proved that a sufficient criterion for the convergence of the following sequence $\ \sqrt{a_1 + \sqrt{a_2 +\:\cdots\: +\sqrt{a_n}}}\ \ $ is that $\rm\displaystyle\ \ {\overline \lim}_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log{a_n}}{2^n}\ < \infty\:.\ $

[image]

Comment: The above solution is from which journal? Can you give me the link?

Comment: @PragyadityaDas: the image is from Collected Papers of Ramanujan.

Answer (score 69):

This is Ramanujan's famous nested radical.

More information can be found here: http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/ramanujanday.pdf

See Also: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadical.html (number 26).

Apparently, this is how he came up with it (sorry, no reference for this claim).

Start with

$$3 = \sqrt{9} = \sqrt{1 + 8} = \sqrt{1 + 2 \cdot 4}$$
$$ = \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{16}} = \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \cdot 5}}$$
$$ = \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{25}}} = \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + 4 \cdot 6}}}$$
etc.

Comment: What a beauty! :D

Comment: I just followed a "possible duplicate" link here and saw that [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/165693) is a "possible duplicate" of yours :-) (+1)

Comment: According to this reasoning,$$4=\sqrt{16}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{\frac{225}{4}}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{...}}}$$. This should go on forever. If I accept your reasoning it implies that I also accept this reasoning. I think you had better prove it by some other technique.

Answer (score 35):

Let me provide a full and simple proof here (6 years later)

Set, for $m<n$
$$
a_{m,n}=\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+(m+1)\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n}}}}.
$$
We shall first show that $$a_{m,n}<m+1,\tag{1}$$ in the following way using
*Backwards induction*. Clearly,
$a_{n,n}=\sqrt{1+n}<1+n$, and if $a_{k+1,n}<k+2$, for some $k<n$, then
$$
a_{k,n}=\sqrt{1+ka_{k+1,n}}<\sqrt{1+k(k+2})=\sqrt{k^2+2k+1}=k+1.
$$
In particular, in the same way we can show that
$$
m+1=\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+(m+1)\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{\color{red}{n^2+2n}}}}}}
$$
Next, observe that
$$
0<m+1-a_{m,n}= \\
=\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{\color{red}{n^2+2n}}}}}
-\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{n}}}} \\
=\frac{m\Big(\sqrt{1+(m+1)\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{\color{red}{n^2+2n}}}}}
-\sqrt{1+(m+1)\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{n}}}}\Big)}{\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{\color{red}{n^2+2n}}}}}
+\sqrt{1+m\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+{n}}}}} \\
<\frac{m}{m+2}(m+2-a_{m+1,n}) <\cdots < \frac{m(m+1)\cdots (n-1)}{(m+2)(m+3)\cdots(n+1)}(n+1-a_{n,n})=\frac{m(m+1)(n+1-\sqrt{n+1})}{n(n+1)}<\frac{m(m+1)}{n}.
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{m,n}=m+1.
$$

Comment: Lol, 6 years later indeed.

Comment: Exactly what I did when I encountered this problem! Nicely done.

Comment: this is beautiful. The original proof never sat well with me, it more or less amounted to knowing the solution beforehand. This is a nice forward proof. +1