# How to find this limit: $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, nested-radicals

**Question:**

> Show that $$A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}}$$ 
>   exists, and find the  best estimate limit $A$.

It is easy to show that

> $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}}\le\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots+\sqrt{1}}}}$$
>   and it is well known that this limit
>   $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots+\sqrt{1}}}}$$ exists.

So
$$A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}}$$

> But can use some math methods to find an approximation to this $A$ by hand?

and  I guess maybe this is true:
$$1<A\le (\pi)^{\frac{1}{e}}?$$

**By the way:**  we can prove  $A$ is a transcendental number?

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: [Not a duplicate, but similar.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48503/nested-radicals-sqrta-sqrt2a-sqrt3a-ldots)

Comment: I konw  your link problem,But My problem is different.and is more interesting.Thank you

Comment: @chinamath After rough a numerical experimentation, it looks very likely that actually $A= (\pi)^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

Comment: Numerically, the number $\sim 1.5218903868642315049804187356992561937433633828577161062431190002880321340$ which is very different from $\pi^{1/e}$.

Comment: Numerically, we should give up on trying to make any conclusions.

Comment: How are you so certain that $A$ is transcendental?

Comment: This question made me smile :)

Comment: I don't get it.  The OP has a proof that the limit exists, and achille hui has calculated the limit to $73$ decimal places.  Is there anything more to do here?

Comment: Yea, find closed form or prove it doesnt exist. How fast does this thing converge? Generally things which depend heavily on the first few terms dont have closed forms.

Comment: For those who don't understand the upper bound (among myself quite recently). From $x = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{+1\sqrt{1+\cdots+\sqrt{1}}}}$ it follows that $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ or $x^2-x-1=0$ hence $x=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: That only shows what $x$ must be if $x$ exists in the first place. To show that $x$ exists we need to check that we have an increasing sequence starting from less than $2$ and that $\sqrt{1+x} < 2$ for any $x<2$.

Answer (score 19):

The **nature** and **closed form** expression of these two **related** constants, i.e., the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html)  and [Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html), are (also) **unknown**. This would suggest that the same holds true for this one as well, meaning that we are dealing with an **open question**.

As far as numeric **approximations** are concerned, $\displaystyle{A\simeq\frac{(\pi+1)\ln4}{1+\ln16}}$ comes close, within an error of **less** than $10^{-8}$.

Comment: You refer to nested square roots of $1$ or $x$. This isn't the case

Comment: The two articles inform us of the following facts: $(1)$. Such expressions are not currently known to possess a closed form. $(2)$. Their nature is yet unknown. Yes, everybody suspects them of being transcendental: But maths is based on demonstration, not suspicion.

Comment: I'm interested: how did you derive your approximation? (I ask because I wouldn't have a clue where to begin with deriving it...)

Comment: By using [this site](http://www.mrob.com/pub/ries/ries.php?target=1.5218903868642315).

Answer (score 7):

The main reason of this answer is that it's impossible to squeeze the content
below into a comment. Disclaimer: it's is only a **partial answer** to the
question as formulated. And it's no way better than the (IMHO final) comment by
[Achille Hui](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui).

Let the function $A(n)$ be defined by:
$$
A(n) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}}
$$
Numerical computation of the sequence in, for example, Pascal is quite simple:

```
function A(N : integer) : double;
var 
  w : double;
  k : integer;
begin
  w := 0;
  for k := N downto 1 do
    w := sqrt(1/k + w);
  A := w;
end;
```

But the strange thing about it is that it's sort of wrong headed iteration. Instead
of going from $A_1$ to $A_n$ it goes from $A_{n+1}$ *down to* $A_1$:
$$
   A_{n+1} = 0 \quad ; \quad A_k = \sqrt{\frac{1}{k} + A_{k+1}} \quad ; \quad 1 \le k \le n
$$
It's called *Backward Recursion* according to the internet (I've never seen it
before). So the question is, remarkably, to find $A$ as:
$$
   A = \lim_{n\to \infty} A_1(n) \qquad \mbox{instead of} \qquad A = \lim_{n\to \infty} A_n
$$
The numerical outcome is, of course, in agreement with Achille's, far less accurate
though (what can be expected from double precision Pascal).

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can get very good approximations by computing:

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$

---

$$b_1=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$b_2=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{7/3}}{2}$$

$$b_3=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Then you use the facts that:

$$A^2-1<b_1$$

$$(A^2-1)^2-\frac{1}{2}<b_2$$

And so on, to calculate upper bounds for $A$ with very good accuracy:

$$A<\sqrt{1+b_1}=1.53819$$

$$A<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+b_2}}=1.52580$$

$$A<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+b_3}}}=1.52300$$

> $$A<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+b_4}}}}=1.52224$$

And so on. This is already very close to the accurate expression. It's a rather easy calculation and can be done by hand if needed.

For the lower boundary you can use $b=1$ (it's rather obvious):

$$A>\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+1}}}}=1.51844$$