# Prove $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, nested-radicals

> Prove $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=3$

I tried to express it as a recursive sequence, but I failed.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165671/convergence-of-the-sequence-sqrt12-sqrt1-sqrt12-sqrt13-sqrt1-sq

Comment: Thanks njguliyev (Iam also searching that solution)