# prove or disprove $\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}}}<\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1}}}}}}$

Tags: inequality

let $n\in N^{+}$ and such $n\ge 2$

prove or disprove
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}}}<\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1}}}}}}\tag{1}$$

and I have use induction prove $$\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}}}<3$$
because $$\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}<k$$
and we  known this Ramanujan's  indentity:  [Prove $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524559/prove-sqrt12-sqrt13-sqrt14-sqrt-cdots-3?rq=1)
and also use indution prove this 
$$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1}}}}}}<3$$
see:[Evaluating the nested radical $ \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}} $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/evaluating-the-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt1-3-sqrt1-cdots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But how to prove $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}}}$$
$$\log L=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\log(k+1)}{2^k}=\quad{\text{LerchPhi}^{0,1,0}}(\frac{1}{2},0,2)=1.0156678457368767......$$
so
$$L=e^{1.01566784573687........}=2.761206841957498033230454646......$$
hence 
$$2.7612.....<3$$

Comment: Thanks,but this inequality for all positive $n$,not only for $n\to +\infty$