# Sum of consecutive square roots inside a square root

Tags: nested-radicals

$$\large\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2+\sqrt{1+2+3+\sqrt{1+2+3+4+\cdots}}}}$$
I saw this somewhere in the internet but, the website didn't provide me any further information. What is the sum of the equation above? What is it called?

Comment: This kind of thing is called a "nested radical" or a "continued radical", and searching for those terms may turn up this example. Be sure to report back if you find anything.

Comment: It is approximately equal to 1.864 458 958 163 488 132 352 003 715

Comment: @AntonioVargas. May I ask how you arrived to this result ? I am more conerned by the procedure than by the "approximate" result. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, certainly.  I asked Mathematica to compute the result to 35 digits of accuracy using [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b27QiuZs), which starts from the innermost element, $\sqrt{m(m+1)/2}$, and works outward through the radicals.  To get the 28 digits I wrote in my comment one needs to calculate at least the 24th element in the sequence (using this method).  I have no error bounds, though, and the only evidence I have that they're correct is that if I increase $m$ by 1 then those digits remain unchanged.

Comment: @AntonioVargas. It is just incredible to see what we can do with 0's and 1's ! Thanks for the code; it is beautiful. Cheers.

Comment: Just an unfinished idea: If you define $f(x)=\sqrt{s(x)+\sqrt{s(x+1)+\sqrt{...}}}$ with $s(x)=x(x+1)/2$, $f$ fulfills the functional equation $f(x)^2=s(x)+f(x+1)$ and your answer is $f(1)$.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the sum of the equation above? What is it called?

It's neither an equation nor a sum, but is a *continued radical* defined as the limit   (as $n\to\infty$) of the sequence of the *nested radicals*
$$
u_n = \sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2 + \cdots + \sqrt{a_n}}} 
$$
where $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$ (the $n^{th}$ triangle number), $n = 1,2,3,...$

---

That this limit *exists* follows from a theorem proved by [T. Vijayaraghavan (1927)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820761):

> For any sequence of nonnegative reals $(a_n)_{n=1,2,3,...}$, the sequence of nested radicals $(u_n)_{n = 1,2,3,...}$ with
>   $$u_n = \sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2 + \cdots + \sqrt{a_n}}}$$
>    converges if and only if there exists a finite upper limit 
>   $$\overline{\lim}\ {\left(\frac{\log{a_n}}{2^n}\right)} < \infty.$$

This clearly holds in the present case, because
$$\overline{\lim}\ {\left(\frac{\log{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{2^n}\right)}  = 0.
$$

---

To  bound the error of $u_n$ as an approximation of the limit, the following consequence of a theorem proved by [Herschfeld (1935)](http://pballew.net/1935Herschfeld.pdf) can be used:

> If $a_i \gt 0 \ \ (i = 1,2,3,...)$, then for all $n \ge 1$,
>   $$0 \le u_{n+1}-u_n \le \frac{1}{2^n}\sqrt{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}}. $$

Substituting $a_i = i(i+1)/2$ and simplifying then gives
$$0 \le u_{n+1}-u_n \le \frac{1}{n!}\sqrt{\frac{n+2}{2^{n+1}}} ,
$$
whence, [noting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) that $n! \ge \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$,
$$0 \le u_{n+1}-u_n \le A \left(\frac{B}{n}\right)^n
$$
where $A = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}} = 0.4886...$ and $B = \frac{e}{\sqrt{2}} = 1.922...$

Now for all $m > n > 1$,

$$\begin{align}
0 \le u_m - u_n & = (u_m - u_{m-1}) + (u_{m-1} - u_{m-2}) + \cdots + (u_{n+1} - u_n) \\
& \le A \left (  \left (\frac{B}{m-1}\right )^{m-1} + \left (\frac{B}{m-2}\right )^{m-2} + \cdots + \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^{n}     \right )\\
& \le A \left (  \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^{m-1} + \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^{m-2} + \cdots + \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^{n}     \right )\\
& \le A \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^n \frac{1 - (\frac{B}{n})^{m-n}}{1 - \frac{B}{n}}\tag{*}
\end{align}
$$
where the [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas) was summed in the last step (noting that $B/n < 1$ for all $n > 1$).

Finally, taking limits with $m \to \infty$ and letting $u = \lim_{m \to\infty}{u_m}$, 
$$0 \le u - u_n \le A \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^n \frac{1}{1 - \frac{B}{n}}.
$$

(Note that (*) above also gives another proof of the *existence* of the limit, by showing the sequence $(u_n)_{n = 1,2,3,...}$ to be Cauchy.)

---

The latter error bound is rather weak, but it suffices to prove, for example, that

$$u = 1.8644589581634881323520037152739437841564220698266...$$

by computing $u_n$ for sufficiently large $n$. For example, $u_n$ has at least $n$ correct digits for any $n \ge 20$, because in that case 
$A \left (\frac{B}{n}\right )^n \frac{1}{1 - \frac{B}{n}} \le 0.5 \ 10^{-n}.
$

---

(Aside)

Here's the [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) program I used to compute the $u_n$:

```
def u(n):
  r = 0
  for k in [1..n][::-1]: r = sqrt(k*(k+1)/2 + r)
  return r

for n in [10..100]: print n, u(n).n(digits=100)
```

Answer (score -2):

As Gerry Myerson said this type of problems are called nested radical.

Let us try the following method: Writing the sequence of partials $$D_n:=
\sqrt {1 + \sqrt {1 + 2 + \sqrt {1 + 2 + 3 + \sqrt {1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +  \ldots  + \sqrt { \ldots  + \sqrt { \ldots  + \sqrt {1 + 2 + 3 +  \ldots  + n} } } } } } } 
$$

Labeling the terms of the series beginning from the last one up to the first one; denoted by $y_1^2,y_1^2,\cdots,y_{n-1}^2,y_n^2$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
&y_n^{2}=1 + 2 + 3 +  \ldots  + n = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\\
&y_{n-1}^{2}=1 + 2 + 3 +  \ldots  + (n-1) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n-1} {k}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}  
\\
&y_{n-2}^{2}=1 + 2 + 3 +  \ldots  + (n-2) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n-2} {k}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}
\\
&\vdots  
\\
&y_{3}^{2}=1 + 2 + 3 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{3} {k}=\frac{(3)(4)}{2}=6
\\
&y_{2}^{2}=1 + 2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2} {k}=\frac{(2)(3)}{2}=3
\\
&y_{1}^{2}=1 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{1} {k}=\frac{(1)(2)}{2}=1
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
D_n  = 
\sqrt {y_1  + \sqrt {y_2  + \sqrt {y_3  +  \ldots  + \sqrt { \ldots  + \sqrt { \ldots  + \sqrt {y_{n - 2}  + \sqrt {y_{n - 1}  + \sqrt {y_n } } } } } } } } 
\end{align}
Now, let us divide $D_n$ into the following subsequences
\begin{align}
 & S_{n,1}^2  = y_n  \\ 
 & S_{n,2}^2  = y_{n - 1}  + S_{n,1}  \\ 
 &S_{n,3}^2  = y_{n - 2}  + S_{n,2}  \\ 
 &S_{n,4}^2  = y_{n - 3}  + S_{n,3}  \\ 
  &\vdots  \\ 
 &S_{n,n - 2}^2  = y_2  + S_{n,n - 1}  \\ 
 &S_{n,n - 1}^2  = y_1  + S_{n,n}  
 \end{align}
Finally, we have
\begin{align}
D_n  &= S_{n,1}^2  + S_{n,2}^2  + S_{n,3}^2  + S_{n,4}^2  +  \ldots  + S_{n,n - 2}^2  + S_{n,n - 1}^2 
\\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n - 1} {S_{n,j}^2 }  
\\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {y_j }  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {S_{n,j} } 
\end{align}
I think this enough to give an indication.

Comment: Sorry, where is the relation to the question?

Comment: Thanks, i made a correction

Comment: It's still not clear to me, how you "divide $D_n$" into the $S^2_{n,j}$, the radicals just disappeared. Also, I think your result is wrong as it has $\lim_{n\to\infty}D_n=\infty$ but we know that a finite limit should exist $\approx 1.8644....$.

Comment: I quote here, "in 1966. Vijayaraghavan proved that a sufficient criterion for the convergence of the following sequence \begin{align}
\sqrt {a_1  + \sqrt {a_2  +  \ldots  + \sqrt {a_n } } } 
\end{align} s that
$\overline {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } } \frac{{\log a_n }}{{2^n }} < \infty $. In our problem, $a_n=y_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so that $
\overline {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } } \frac{{\log a_n }}{{2^n }} = \overline {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } } \frac{{\log {\textstyle{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 2}}}}{{2^n }} = 0
$

Comment: Oohh, i quote from (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/limit-of-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt13-sqrt1-cdots?rq=1) see also (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61048/definition-of-convergence-of-a-nested-radical-sqrta-1-sqrta-2-sqrta-3?rq=1), nice discussion.

Comment: Yes, I don't question the existence of the limit. My point is, that your result $D_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}S^2_{nj}\rightarrow\infty$ and therefore is wrong.

Comment: I think that also. I will keep thinking. Thx