# Interesting & beautiful Series/Products/Nested Radicals/Continued Fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, infinite-product, continued-fractions

I've encountered various stunning series, products, nested radicals and continued fractions, such as the ones listed below:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+...$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...$$
$$e=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...$$
$$\frac{2}{\pi}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\times\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{2}\times\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}{2}\times...$$
$$3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+...}}}}$$
I've been interested in finding some other stunning series, products, nested radicals or continued fractions; if you know any, would you mind posting them below?

Thank you.

Please note, I do not want series or products etc that are polynomials, eg Taylor/Maclaurin series (beautiful as they may be!). I would only like expressions with constant terms.

Comment: [Wau has several interesting representations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFLkou8NvJo)

Comment: See this popular [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871639/denesting-radicals-like-sqrt3-sqrt32-1). Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/evaluating-the-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt1-3-sqrt1-cdots).

Comment: I noticed that someone voted to close the question. If you have any similar feelings, can you please comment why?

Comment: @A-levelStudent I can agree that the formulas involving $\pi$ are beautiful, but the ones relating to $e$ and $\phi$ are, in my opinion, just the definitions of $e$ and $\phi$... (I did not vote to close, however)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe you have a fair point there, I will change them. Incidentally, is there any other infinite series that has been found to calculate $e$?

Comment: Do not care about one close-vote (not mine). This is a somewhat subjective question , this is probably the reason for the close-vote. But you have a $+2$-score, so currently you need not worry.

Comment: Since "stunning" is not a mathematical notion, you'd better ask this elsewhere. No, seriously, this is just attracting personal opinions.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't think that's fair. I think all mature mathematicians can agree on whether an equality is stunning or not.

Comment: @Gerben everyone is entitled to their own opinion :) I am afraid I heartily disagree with you. Formulae like $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ are easily proved but are still constantly praised and adored by the mathematical community. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity

Comment: @Gerben ok. I am sorry I have bothered you.

Comment: Nah do your thing and enjoy, be happy and cheerful :) it's just not my thing.